# Occasional "Permissions Error" returned when running a program that creates many files

Tags: python, python-3.x, permissions, subprocess, popen

Currently I have the following code:

```
# Open a place holding output file
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:

        # Run BOLSIG-
        r = Popen("%s %s" % (bolsig, infile), stdout=f, cwd=outputdir)
        # Wait for BOLSIG- to complete
        Popen.wait(r)

# Remove the created output file as it is not used and BOLSIG- creates it's own file
    remove('out.txt')
```

It takes an .exe file *(bolsig)* and runs its program and inputs into the running program a file name *(infile)* which the program then opens and executes accordingly outputting its own file. This script is often run with up to 1000 input files.

The only way I could get Popen to allow *bolsig* to save its output file was to create a "holding" file *out.txt* and the remove it later. Often this works fine, but occasionally the program will run outputting 80/90/100 files then suddening the line,

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
```

will throw the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/minec/Desktop/College/4th_Year/Final Year Project/Program/Master-Program.py", line 1129, in <module>
   main()
File "C:/Users/minec/Desktop/College/4th_Year/Final Year Project/Program/Master-Program.py", line 45, in main
   outputdir = bolsig_minus(runfilelist)
File "C:/Users/minec/Desktop/College/4th_Year/Final Year Project/Program/Master-Program.py", line 496, in bolsig_minus
   with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'out.txt'
```

Does anyone know why it is throwing this error only occasionally? If so, how to do I fix it or modify the code to not have use the *out.txt* file at all but still allow Popen to save it's file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that from time to time you try to write to `out.txt` before it was fully removed. What you can do:

1. Add some `time.sleep()` at before starting a new script
2. Check if `out.txt` is not existing before running `Popen`
3. Use this library for temporary files handling: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html

I think that the best approach will be number 3 combined with number 2.